# If p+q+r+s=45 and (p+2)+(q−2)+(r×2)+(s/2)=45 then what is the value of p,q,r,s?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$ p+q+r+s=45 $$ and $$(p+2)+(q−2)+(r×2)+(s/2)=45$$  then what is the value of $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$?

Comment: Would you call the reception of your previous question, good? Reiterating seems to mean you do not care...

Comment: Why don't you first add *to your post* (by editing your post) the work you've put into solving your question. And/or, share with us where you found this question (text? lecture? exam or quiz?), and where you feel stuck.

Comment: @Debar, amWhy  is right

Comment: If I was right,$\textbf{this system of equation has infinitely many solutions}$

Comment: You  may assume $\textbf{r and s as constants (any two of the variable),then this system became two equation with two unknown.NOW YOU CAN SOLVE IT BY ELIMINATION OR CRAMER'S RULE OR SOME OTHER METHODS}$

Comment: Sorry for wrong question. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Equation 2 becomes, $ p+q+(r+s)*2 = 45 $
So, $$ r+s = 0 $$$$ p+q=45 $$This is the only thing you can do with these two equations...

Comment: Cool,now we get infinitely many solution,I think you miss it.

Comment: Sorry for wrong question. Please see updated question.